# Introduction to speech processing with code and examples?

Tags: speech-recognition, reference-request, speech-processing

Can anyone suggest an introduction to speech processing,
class notes or books
accompanied by programs that can be run to see what the algorithms do ?
For example, in Burrus et al., [Computer-Based Exercises for Signal Processing Using Matlab](http://books.google.com/books?isbn=0132198258),
20 of the 400 pages are on speech processing. But it's from 1994;
there must be other hands-on books ?
Books with reviews like the following may have their uses, but are not what I'm looking for:

> I found this book comprehensive but incomprehensible, primarily because of the
>   lack of real-world examples. It would benefit from a series of programming exercises
>   with training sets

(This question may be a tall order — not many people ar good at theory *and* practice *and* explaining.)

(Should this be a community wiki ?)

Comment: This question does not follow our standard QA format because it's completely open-ended. However, if it gets good responses I'll convert it into a community wiki. Otherwise I may have to close it. You can try and make it more specific about what precisely you're looking for. That would help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Prof. Rabiner's slides at http://www.ece.ucsb.edu/Faculty/Rabiner/ece259/ . They also have some matlab code examples which you can try.

Comment: Hi denis,  I am currently taking the course "Speech signal processing" by Prof. Umesh in IIT Madras (India). He teaches us from these particular slides. They are highly informative.

Comment: Thanks.
Have you taken or taught a class with this ?
The link "Introduction to Digital Speech processing.pdf" on that page
gets the whole book by Rabiner and Schafer, 194p,
with a list of ~ 50 books in various areas up to 2008 .
(Confusingly, the downloaded pdf is called final_speech_paper_1_2008.pdf .)
However the few programs are for i/o and plotting, no algorithms.

Comment: Hi Denis, I have taken the course, did not teach :). I am an undergraduate final year student. In case you need some basic codes, you can contact me. I have worked on some assignments which teach basics like zero crossings, energy based segmentation etc.